# Notebook partitioning

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning

I just bought a new notebook. It's a Dell with 1TB HDD and 32GB SSD. It comes pre-installed with Windows 10 PRO (I do not have the installation disc). I have not installed anything else.

I read it is a good idea to partition your HDD, keeping your OS separate from your personal data. So, I attempted this with disk management.

Currently I have 930-ish GB drive C (OS) and a few recovery drives. Disk management showed that the minimum I can reduce the C drive to is about 450GB. I was hoping it would be about 80-100GB. So should I even bother partitioning my HDD?

Comment: Pretty pointless, imo. If the drive fails, you lose both partitions anyway, rest of the time you need to mess with symlinking. Only really useful if you have a penchant for fiddling with/breaking the OS.

Comment: I strongly agree with @Tetsujin, there negative implications and risks are much greater than any gains that come from partitioning in this instance.

Answer (score 1):

I'd skip the partition, at least on windows. When a partition is screwed up on windows, it's usually because the entire drive failing, or because of a broken partition table, the latter of which can be caused by a failed repartition operation.

In general, the two comments are in line with what I'm thinking: A successful repartition is not very useful and adds more work, while a failed repartition can break the entire installation.

TL;DR: Not worth it.